# Can ROS INDIGO & ROS I HYDRO communicate each other?

Tags: ros-hydro, ros-industrial, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have downloaded ROS indigo version. since i need tp use path planning in my project i intend to use ROS industrial. Does ros industrial indigo version exist or ROS industrial hydro can be used with ROS indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220045/can-ros-indigo-&-ros-i-hydro-communicate-each-other?/) by [alexi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24636/alexi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2015-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-28**:
Could you please clarify what you want to do exactly? MoveIt for instance is *not* part of ROS-Industrial. All the other packages in ROS-Industrial (Descartes fi) can be build from source on Hydro, Indigo and Jade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Does ros industrial indigo version exist

Depends on what components you're thinking about but yes, [industrial_core](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_core?distro=indigo) package suite and driver package of several industrail robots (e.g. [fanuc](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc_driver?distro=indigo), [UR](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot?distro=indigo), [abb](http://wiki.ros.org/abb?distro=indigo)) are available in Indigo via DEB (apt-get-ttable).

> or ROS industrial hydro can be used with ROS indigo

It *might* work but cross-distro compatibility is never guaranteed AFAIK.
Cf. [distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions#What_is_a_Distribution.3F).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2